# Function which accept any STL container

Tags: c++, templates

I need to implement a template function that accepts any STL container. And based on what kind of container to perform certain actions.

Example:

```
template <class Container, class T>
void func(Container<T> container) {
    if (container == std::map) {
        ...
    } else {
        ... 
    }
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1; 
    func(v1); // ok
    std::vector<double> v2;
    func(v2); // ok
    std::map<int, double> m1;
    func(m1); // ok
    std::list<int> l1;
    func(l1); // ok
}
```

Comment: What is better withis solution than having several overloads `template <typename T>
void func(std::vector<T> const& container)` and so on?

Comment: @user2672165, my guess is the `else` part, although you can achieve that with a final templated overload.

Comment: Do you need to do different things for different containers?

Comment: @Caleth, yes i want use std::accumulate for any container

Comment: Do you mean `std::accumulate(container.begin(), container.end(), /* other args */)`? You don't need to know the container's type to do that.

Comment: @Caleth, solution for vector doesnt work for map for example

Comment: I'd fix that at the call site `func(map | std::views::values)` (or [a predecessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17) (with [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)) to check the type at compile-time, and apply [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) (since C++11) because these containers take multiple template parameters. e.g.

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, class... T>
void func(const Container<T...>& container) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Container<T...>, std::map<T...>>) {
        ...
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Container<T...>, std::vector<T...>>) {
        ...
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Container<T...>, std::list<T...>>) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

PS: It depends on your intent but changing the parameter to pass-by-reference-to-const to avoid unnecessary copy might be a good idea.

Comment: This doesn't work with `std::array`, because of it's non-type parameter

Comment: @Caleth, how fix it ?

Comment: @Caleth Well, we can do that with more hand-written traits... https://wandbox.org/permlink/zAkfV11N9JE2XFGE

Comment: Nitpick: `std::string` is a container too

Comment: @Caleth Just for testing. If both containers and other types including built-in types could be passed I think much more hand-written traits are needed.

Comment: I really like this answer and it has my vote. I just had to add an alternative below :-)

Comment: @songyuanyao , how can i use std::accumulator in your case for map or array? ?

Comment: @Yaniboze [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) ?

Comment: @songyuanyao, yes

Comment: @songyuanyao, I just want to calculate the sum of all the elements in any container

Comment: @Yaniboze For `std::array`, just pass iterators and the initial value to `std::accumulate`, i.e. use the 1st overloaded one; for `std::map` you can use the 2nd overload and pass a function object additionally. See the page I linked for more.

Comment: @songyuanyao, can u show me some example for map? i have trouble when try to create std::pair<T...>

Answer (score 2):

Since you're making one implementation per container anyway, you could make overloads directly. It'll work in C++11 and has the benefit of having the template parameters easily available in each overload.

```
template <class T, size_t N>
void func(const std::array<T,N>& c) {
    std::cout << "array " << c.size() << '\n';
}

template <class T, class Alloc>
void func(const std::vector<T,Alloc>& c) {
    std::cout << "vector " << c.size() << '\n';
}

template <class T, class Alloc>
void func(const std::list<T,Alloc>& c) {
    std::cout << "list " << c.size() << '\n';
}

template <class Key, class T, class Comp, class Alloc>
void func(const std::map<Key,T,Comp,Alloc>& c) {
    std::cout << "map " << c.size() << '\n';
}

template <class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc>
void func(const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& c) {
    std::cout << "basic_string " << c.size() << '\n';
}

// add more of the containers you aim to support here
```